# Haskell filter out circular permutations

Tags: haskell

You have a list with N elements
You only want to print elements that are not circular permuations of other elements of the same list

To check if two strings are the circular permutations of each other I do this, which works fine :

```
string1 = "abc"
string2 = "cab"
stringconc = string1 ++ string1
if string2 `isInfixOf` stringconc
then -- it's a circular permuation
else -- it's not
```

Edit : As one comment pointed that out, this test only work for strings of the same size

Back to the real use case :

```
checkClean :: [String] -> [String] -> IO String
checkClean [] list = return ""
checkClean (x:xs) list = do
let sequence = cleanInfix x list
  if sequence /= "abortmath"
    then putStr sequence
    else return ()
  checkClean xs list
```

cleanInfix :

```
cleanInfix :: String -> [String] -> String
cleanInfix seq [] = seq
cleanInfix seq (x:xs) = do
  let seqconc = x ++ x
  if seq `isInfixOf` seqconc && seq /= x
    then "abortmath"
    else cleanInfix seq xs
```

However this just outputs... nothing
With some research I found out that sequence in checkClean is always "abortmath" 
Also I'm not quite comfortable with this "flag" abortmath, because if by any chance one element of the list is "abortmath", well..

For example : 
if I have a list composed of :

```
NUUNNFFUF
FFUFNUUNN
```

I should write 
NUUNNFFUF

Comment: I'm quite new around here, so if someone could explain why the question received a downvote it would be nice, so I don't make the same mistake twice

Comment: I honestly don't know why, maybe someone doesn't like Haskell, the question seems fine to me, though I am not sure how to answer it. Good luck, and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I don't think your circular permutation test is right. What if `string2` is `"abcabc"`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have pointed out that I have other tests before that one that check that every element of the list are the same size (working with debruijn sequence of size alphabetsize^order) I'm going to edit the question to specify that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you call your initial code (question) with something like that:

```
result = ["NUUNNFFUF", "FFUFNUUNN"]
main = do
    checkClean result result
```

It won't print anything because:

- the first call of `cleanInfix` has the arguments following arguments: `"NUUNNFFUF"` and `["NUUNNFFUF", "FFUFNUUNN"]`
- in `cleanInfix`, since `seq == x`  you have a recursive call with the following arguments: `"NUUNNFFUF"` and `["FFUFNUUNN"]`
- now, `"NUUNNFFUF"` is a real permutation of `"FFUFNUUNN"`: `cleanInfix` returns `"abortmath"`, and `checkClean` returns `()`
- then you have a recursive call of `checkClean` with following arguments: `"FFUFNUUNN"` and `["NUUNNFFUF", "FFUFNUUNN"]`
- again, `"FFUFNUUNN"` is a real permutation of `"NUUNNFFUF"`: `cleanInfix` returns `"abortmath"`, and `checkClean` returns `()`
- this is the end.

Basically, x is a permutation of y and y is a permutation of x, thus x and y are discarded.

Your answer works, but it is horribly complicated.

I won't try to improve either of your codes, but I will make a general comment: you should (you *really* should) avoid returning a monad when you don't need to: in the question, `checkClean` just needs to remove duplicates (or "circular duplicates") from a list. That's totally functional: you have all the information you need. Thus, remove those `do`s, `let`s and `return`s!

Now, let's try to focus on this:

> You have a list with N elements You only want to print elements that are not circular permuations of other elements of the same list

Why don't you use your initial knowledge on circular permutations?

```
isCircPermOf x y = x `isInfixOf` (y ++ y)
```

Now, you need  a function that takes a sequence and a list of sequences, and return only the elements of the second that are not circular permutations of the first :

```
filterCircDuplicates :: String -> [String] -> [String]
filterCircDuplicates seq [] = []
filterCircDuplicates seq (x:xs) =
    if seq `isCircPermOf` x
    then removeCircDuplicates seq xs
    else x:removeCircDuplicates seq xs
```

This pattern is well know, and you can use `filter` to simplify it:

```
filterCircDuplicates seq l = filter (\x -> !seq `isCircPermOf` x) l
```

Or better:

```
filterCircDuplicates seq = filter (not.isCircPermOf seq)
```

Note the signature: `not.isCircPermOf seq :: String -> Boolean`. It returns true if the current element is not a circular permutation of `seq`. (You don't have to add the list argument.)

Final step: you need a function that takes a list and return this list without (circular) duplicates.

```
removeCircDuplicates :: [String] -> [String]
removeCircDuplicates [] = []
removeCircDuplicates (x:xs) = x:filterCircDuplicates x (removeCircDuplicates xs)
```

When your list has a head and a tail, you clean the tail, then remove the duplicates of the first element of the tail, and keep this first element.

Again, you have a well known pattern, a `fold`:

```
removeCircDuplicates = foldr (\x acc -> x:filterCircDuplicates x acc) []
```

It removes the duplicates from right to left.

And if you want a one-liner:

```
Prelude Data.List> foldr (\x -> ((:) x).filter(not.(flip isInfixOf (x++x)))) [] ["abcd", "acbd", "cdab", "abdc", "dcab"]
["abcd","acbd","abdc"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The wonders you can make with a pen and some paper...

So if anyone is interested here is how I solved it, it's probably badly optimised but at least it works (I'm just trying to learn haskell, so it's good enough for now)

```
-- cleanInfix function
cleanInfix :: String -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]                                                                    
cleanInfix sequence [] cleanlist = cleanlist                                                                           
cleanInfix sequence (x:xs) cleanlist = do 
-- this is where I check for the circular permuation                                                                                  
  let sequenceconc = x ++ x                                                                                                   
  if sequence `isInfixOf` sequenceconc                                                                                        
    then cleanInfix sequence xs (delete x cleanlist)                                                                        
    else cleanInfix sequence xs cleanlist                                                                                   


-- checkClean Function
checkClean :: [String] -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]                                                                  
checkClean [] listesend cleanlist = cleanlist                                                                            
checkClean (x:xs) listesend cleanlist = do
-- The first delete is to avoid checking if an element is the circular permuation of... itself, because it obviously is... in some way                                                                                  
  let liste2 = cleanInfix x (delete x listesend) cleanlist                                                                  
  checkClean xs (delete x listesend) liste2 


 -- Clean function, first second and third are the command line argument don't worry about them                                                                                                                        
clean first second third = do                                                                                                 
  -- create of the result list by asking user for input

  let printlist = checkClean result result result -- yes, it's the same list, three times                                                                            
  print printlist -- print the list
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you can factor out some repetition here: ``if sequence `isInfixOf` sequenceconc then cleanInfix sequence xs (delete x cleanlist) else cleanInfix sequence xs cleanlist`` can be written ``cleanInfix sequence xs $ if sequence `isInfixOf` sequenceconc then delete x cleanlist else cleanlist`` or even ``cleanInfix sequence xs $ (if sequence `isInfixOf` sequenceconc then delete x else id) cleanlist``.